# How to convert comma separated array to rows in hive

Tags: sql, hive

I try to pull anchorurl summary for each transactionid in my table, so I need convert comma separated array to rows.

This is running in Hive, mostly use sql command. (In DDC of Dbeaver actually)

```
SELECT      eventdate
            ,transactionid
            ,platform
            ,storeid
            ,StringTokenizerDelim(anchorurls,",") 
                over (PARTITION by eventdate,transactionid,platform,storeid)
FROM        scribe.tblscriberelatedsearchresults
order by    1,2,3
;


SELECT      eventdate
            ,transactionid
            ,platform
            ,storeid
            ,url
FROM        scribe.tblscriberelatedsearchresults lateral view explode(split(anchorurls,",")) anchorurls as url
order by    1,2,3
;

SELECT      eventdate
            ,transactionid
            ,platform
            ,storeid
            ,split_part(anchorurls,",") 
                over (PARTITION by eventdate,transactionid,platform,storeid)
FROM        scribe.tblscriberelatedsearchresults
order by    1,2,3
;
```

SELECT      eventdate
            ,transactionid
            ,platform
            ,storeid
            ,split(anchorurls,",") 
FROM        scribe.tblscriberelatedsearchresults
order by    1,2,3
;

One more thing is: 
I find command "explode" can get those array out perfectly, but I don't know how to also keep the other columns such as transactionid with them (which is the foreign key for joining another table)

Originally it was:

```
eventdate   transactionid   platform   storeid   "url1","url2","url3"
```

I expect it to be:

```
eventdate   transactionid   platform   storeid   url1
eventdate   transactionid   platform   storeid   url2
eventdate   transactionid   platform   storeid   url3
```

Error message:

> Reason: SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: ('HY000', "[HY000]
>   [Cloudera][HiveODBC] (35) Error from Hive: error code: '40000' error
>   message: 'Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException
>   Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group
>   must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular
>   dependencies.\nUnderlying error: Invalid function split_part'. (35)
>   (SQLExecDirectW)")   Position: 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lateral view explode to get output you're looking for

Please follow this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView) explained in detail with the examples

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I am looking for, thank you so much!